# Null token returned

Tags: java, automated-tests, rest-assured, web-api-testing

I'm testing API endpoints. The problem is when I check on Swagger, it returns a valid token, but in my testing it returns NULL. Can you point out where I'm doing the wrong thing?

```
 public static void createOrganization() {
    Map<String, String> org = new HashMap();
    org.put("directorName", "name");
    org.put("email", "email@gmail.com");
    org.put("website", "www.site.com");
    org.put("phoneNumber", "000111");

    String registrationToken = given().
            contentType("application/json").
            body(org).
            when().
            post("/v3/organizations").
            then().
            extract().path("registrationToken");

    System.out.println("Token: "+ registrationToken);
```

Output: Token: null

UPDATE: 
Maybe I'm using extract() incorrectly, maybe there's a different solution to use the generated values later. Since for registerDevice() I'm getting NULL as well.

```
public static void registerDevice(){
    String clientDeviceId =
    given().
            param("phoneNumber", "000111").
            param("model", "samsung").
            param("platform", "0").
            param("push_token",SenimEnvironmentVars.testPushToken).
            param("uuid", SenimEnvironmentVars.testUUID).
            param("version", "7.1").
            when().
            post("/v3/user-devices").
            then().
            contentType("application/json").
            extract().path("clientDeviceId");

    System.out.println("Device ID: "+ clientDeviceId); //also prints NULL
}
```

Is there any other ways to generate tokens, device IDs etc. and use them later?

Comment: Is the path has the value entered correctly?'/' or something is needed right to make a path?

Comment: show please your configuration of rest-assured. Server's host, port, basepath, etc...

Comment: @VladislavKoroteev since other tests are running, I dont think it's the path. However here it is:  public static void setup() {

        String basePathStr = System.getProperty("server.base");
        if(basePathStr==null){
            basePathStr = "";
        }
        basePath = basePathStr;

        String baseHost = System.getProperty("server.host");
        if(baseHost==null){
            baseHost = "http://localhost:8080";
        }
        baseURI = baseHost;
    }

Comment: Have you tried logging the output to see what it returns - `then().log().body()`

Comment: @HaC I tried log().bod(), it prints out the generated token, but when I want to extract it, why it's NULL ?

Comment: Please share what the log output was. It may be a jsonpath issue.

Comment: @HaC That;s what it prints out: 
 {
    "content": {
        "registrationToken": "pdlh4ldhh5611du313hqkum6sc",
        "statusId": 0
    },
    "messages": null
}

Comment: In that case, the path should be `extract().path("content.registrationToken")`

Comment: @HaC thank you very much !!! It worked.

Answer (score 0):

As [documentation](https://github.com/rest-assured/rest-assured/wiki/Usage#extracting-values-from-the-response-after-validation) says

> You can extract values from the response or return the response
>   instance itself after you've done validating the response by using the
>   extract method

So try to write after `then` some validating method like `contentType(JSON).`

Comment: I have re-written it as the documentation states (
                        body(org).
                        when().
                        post("/v3/organizations").
                        then().
                        contentType("application/json").
                        extract().path("registrationToken");) , still getting the same error. 
Cannot get property 'registrationToken' on null object

Comment: In this comments url of request contains "v3", but in original question it doesn't. Are you confident in your basePath?

Comment: Sorry for confusing, probably I removed while editing and checking the base path. I do have v3, still the same error